# Numerically append binary numbers in np.array

Tags: python, numpy

Considering the following example array :

```
a = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0])
```

Which could be of any dtype (int, float...)

How would I get the following output without using nasty loops and string casts ?

```
np.array([0b01,0b10,0b11,0b10,0b10])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = a.astype(int)
output = a[0::2] * 2 + a[1::2]
```

Gives the array you've described (though it doesn't print in binary).